# Public API for the new Notes app in iOS9 and OS X 10.11 El Capitan

Tags: ios, macos, swift, api, frameworks

Apple is going to seriously improve Notes.app in iOS 9 and OS X 10.11, and I'm considering to build something that works with that, if it's possible.

My requirement is to **allow my user to write notes into the Notes.app database** from my app; those notes will be then synced via the CloudKit backend used by Notes. I don't want to build a separate note-taking app with CloudKit sync, I just need to "integrate" some notes.

My understanding (after searching here and Google) is that, for iOS 8 and earlier, there was no public API, so the kind of access that EventKit allows for Reminders and Calendar was not allowed for Notes. Am I right, there wasn't any?

If so, **is there a public API for iOS 9 and El Capitan**? What's the framework name, if said API exists?

Thanks in advance,

@cdf1982

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-9.0/index.html

there are no new public api for notes